# passing php values to js file

Tags: php, javascript

simple jquery document ready and then I need some value from php to be alerted
for example remote address.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    string1="<?= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>";
    alert(string1);
```

When I write like this result is

```
<?= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>
```

What's wrong ? no way to pass some php inside js file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> no way to pass some php inside js file ?

The file has to be run through the PHP pre-processor. This is usually done by giving the file a `.php` file extension (although you can configure webservers so that isn't needed).

If you are serving up something that isn't HTML, then make sure you specify the content type.

```
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
```

Comment: You need it in a PHP file that outputs JavaScript (and such a file could then be the target of `<script src="someJavaScript.js"></script>`).

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you can't, because JS is client based and PHP is server based.

Comment: I was trying to write nice, I mean making js files for js, php for php. So instead of that I must echo everything inside php again ? :(

Comment: to be honest with you I think you need proper separation of PHP and JS. You could probably have both without having to echo, you just need to plan it properly. But if it comes to echo, it is nothing that I haven't done :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using the normal tags and print with an echo.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code cannot be executed in files with extensions other than `.php/.php5` (you might have used .js or .html)

Try this

```
<?php echo "<script type=''text/javascript>"; ?>
$(document).ready(function() {
    string1="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>";
    alert(string1);
});
<?php echo "</script>"; ?>
```

Save the file as .php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your web server allows  tags, maybe try . Secondly rather than trying to write to a .js file. You should use a .php file and write the JavaScript inside the HTML within  tags.